# How to create sliding DIV on click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking to create a slide out DIV, like the one [here](http://shutterbugtheme.tumblr.com/) when you press "Contact". Does anybody know of anything similar to this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Making use [jQuery's `slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) method could help you do this.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dJS4g/)

HTML:

```
<div id="contact">
    Contact me!
</div>
<a href="#" id="toggle">Contact</a>
```

CSS:

```
#contact
{
    display: none;
    background: grey;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function()
{
     $("a#toggle").click(function()
     {
         $("#contact").slideToggle();
         return false;
     }); 
});
```

Comment: Can I change the speed with this?

Comment: @EarlLarson:  If you read the documentation page I linked to, you'll notice that `slideToggle`'s first parameter is *duration*.

Comment: Oh haha I'm blind! Thanks so much this was so simple!

Answer (score 15):

If you don't want to use jQuery and you can stick to modern browsers you can try:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/EVyE8/

HTML:

```
<div id="slide">click me</div>
```

CSS:

```
#slide {
    height: 50px;
    transition:             height 500ms ease;
        -moz-transition:    height 500ms ease;
        -ms-transition:     height 500ms ease;
        -o-transition:      height 500ms ease;
        -webkit-transition: height 500ms ease;
}
```

Script:

```
document.getElementById( 'slide' ).addEventListener( 'click', function() {

    this.style.height == '50px' || this.style.height == ''
        ? this.style.height = '150px' 
        : this.style.height = '50px';

}, false );
```

Comment: Thanks ThinkingStiff.  JQuery can be quite heavy for a simple animation.

Answer (score 6):

yet another sample, but without jquery, and with a class add/remove approach :)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/1wbh8pqj/

The main idea is that you have two classes, one of them applies to the slider, and the another, says how the slider should show when it is expanded.

```
.slider {
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;

    transition:         height 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition:    height 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition:     height 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition:      height 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.5s ease;
}

.slided {
    height: 100px;
}
```

so, you have to set the 'slided' class to the slider when it has to be expanded, and remove it when the slider has to be shrinked, and using the super-mega-uber-awesome css transition, the height will smoothly change :)

```
var expander = document.getElementById("expander");

expander.addEventListener("click", function () {
 var slider = document.getElementsByClassName("slider")[0];

  if (slider.classList.contains("slided")) {
    slider.classList.remove("slided");
  } else {
    slider.classList.add("slided");
  }

});
```

ohbtw, the html:

```
<div class="slider">i am teh slidah!! :D</div>
<div class="content">and i am the content XD</div>
<div id="expander">click me to expand/hide the slidah! :O</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

### Another sample

#### Sample

http://jsfiddle.net/9cdYR/

#### HTML

```
<div id="slide">
    Slide content<br />
    Slide content<br />
    Slide content<br />
    </div>
<div id="content">
    Content<br />
    Content<br />
    Content<br />
</div>

<button id="slide_button">Slide it</button>
```

#### CSS

```
#content {
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

#slide {
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

#### JS

```
$('#slide_button').click(function() {
    $('#slide').animate({
        height: 'toggle'
    }, 1500, function() {
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery, you make the div and add display:none with css. Then, something like:

```
$('.button').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#mydiv').slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[The almighty jQuery comes to a rescue, once again](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/).

If you don't want to use jquery, just set a timer and increase the height.