# Slide down animation from display:none to display:block?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

Is there a way to animate display:none to display:block using CSS so that the hidden div slides down instead of abruptly appearing, or should I go about this a different way?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#box').click(function() {
        $(this).find(".hidden").toggleClass('open');
    });
});
```

```css
#box {
    height:auto;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.hidden {
    height:200px;
    display:none;
}
    .hidden.open {
        display:block;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
    Initial Content
    <div class="hidden">
        This is hidden content
    </div>
</div>
```

## And a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6C42Q/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Slide down and slide up div on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279733/slide-down-and-slide-up-div-on-click)

Comment: @TheOneWhoPrograms That question isn't about jQuery or onClick.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, there is a way:
http://jsfiddle.net/6C42Q/12/

By using CSS3 transitions, and manipulate height, rather than display property:

```
.hidden {
    height: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.5s linear;
       -moz-transition: height 0.5s linear;
        -ms-transition: height 0.5s linear;
         -o-transition: height 0.5s linear;
            transition: height 0.5s linear;
}

.hidden.open {
     height: 200px;
     -webkit-transition: height 0.5s linear;
        -moz-transition: height 0.5s linear;
         -ms-transition: height 0.5s linear;
          -o-transition: height 0.5s linear;
             transition: height 0.5s linear;
}
```

More here: [Slide down div on click Pure CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412054/slide-down-div-on-click-pure-css)

Comment: Doesn't work. I try to click on the black bar (initial content) and nothing happens.

Comment: This does not answer the original question of animating display: none to display: block. This isimportant for accessibility, ensuring hidden content is not in the tab index etc...

Comment: we don't need to add transition to sub class when the main class already has it

Comment: But you need to know the height in order to do the animation. and you dont know it inside the css.

Answer (score 15):

Since you're already using jQuery, the simplest thing is just to use slideDown(). http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/

There's also slideToggle().

Then you don't need to manually do all the browser-specific transition css.

Comment: I was building this all out manually because I'd somehow overlooked `slideDown()`. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 8):

I like the idea of CSS transitions, but it's still very jumpy. Sometimes the max-height has to be set to a very high number because of dynamic content which renders the transition useless as it's very jumpy. So, I went back to jQuery, but it had its own faults. inline elements are jumpy.

I found this to work for me:

```
$(this).find('.p').stop().css('display','block').hide().slideDown();
```

The stop stops all previous transitions.
The css makes sure it's treated as a block element even if it's not.
The hide hides that element, but jquery will remember it as a block element.
and finally the slideDown shows the element by sliding it down.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for :) How can I slide it back up?

Comment: Probably use slideUp instead of slideDown I'm guessing.
`$(this).find('.p').stop().css('display','block').hide().slideUp();`
Or you can slideToggle?
`$(this).find('.p').stop().css('display','block').hide().slideToggle();`

Comment: Thanks! a simple `.stop().slideUp()` did the job :)

Answer (score 6):

We can use `visibility: hidden` to `visibility: visible` instead of `display: none` to `display: block` property. And using `max-height` instead of `hight` should keep the element to have auto height.

See this example:

```js
function toggleSlide () {
  const div = document.querySelector('div')
  
  if (div.classList.contains('open')) {
    div.classList.remove('open')
  } else {
    div.classList.add('open')
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: visibility .5s, max-height .5s;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  /* additional style */
  background: grey;
  color: white;
  padding: 0px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

div.open {
  visibility: visible;
  /* Set max-height to something bigger than the box could ever be */
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>First paragraph</p>
  <p>Second paragraph</p>
</div>


<button
  onclick="toggleSlide()"
>
  toggle slide
</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

What about

`$("#yourdiv").animate({height: 'toggle'})`;

Toggle will switch your div on/off, and the animate should make it appear from below. In this scenario, you don't need the specific CSS to "hide" it.

Answer (score 0):

I did this workaround for the navigation header in my React site.

This is the regular visible css class

```
.article-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

This is the class that is attached to the div (when scrolled in my case)

```
.hidden {
  top: -50px !important;
  transition: top 0.5s ease-in-out;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use also

```
$('#youDiv').slideDown('fast');
```

or you can tell that the active div goes up then the called one goes down

```
$('.yourclick').click(function(e) {
       var gett = $(this).(ID);
       $('.youractiveDiv').slideUp('fast', function(){
        $('.'+gett).slideDown(300);
       });
});
```

Something like that.