# How can I create accordion look/feel javascript which will allow several sections to be expanded at once?

Tags: javascript, toggle

I want to be able to expand multiple panels of accordion with the following markup. I also need to use expand/collapse icons accordingly. 
 Is there a simple way to get it done with JavaScript?

**My html code:**

```
<ul class="usa-accordion">
<li>
<button class="usa-accordion-button"
aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="heading-1">
Heading 1
</button>
<div id="amendment-1" class="usa-accordion-content">
<p>
- some text - some text - some text -
</p>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<button class="usa-accordion-button"
aria-controls="heading-2">
Heading 2
</button>
<div id="amendment-2" class="usa-accordion-content">
<p>
- some text - some text - some text -
</p>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

So far, I've created this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ys01u21/1/) from your code above.
Here is how it works.

1. added a `click event listener` on each `button`
2. when clicked, checking if the content is `expanded` or not. Hiding expanded content before revealing the hidden content.
3. Created `CSS` classes to display and and hide the content.

If you need animations, like in an actual Accordion, you can add CSS transitions to change the height. See this [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24314687/slide-down-animation-from-displaynone-to-displayblock)